# Asynchronous code not executing asexpected

Tags: dart, asynchronous

I'm retrieving some data from FireBase but the following code returns null

```
var taxes = new List();
    Future.wait(providerTax.map((e) async {
      var details;
      await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .doc(e['tax'].path)
          .get()
          .then((value) => details = value.data());

      taxes.add({
        'taxID': e['identifier'],
        'taxName': details['taxID'],
        'taxRate': details['unitText'],
        'taxAmount': store.state.numberWorkedHours *
            offer.data()['price'] *
            details['value']
      });
    }));
```

The same code called differently works and returns the expected result

```
List tempTax = new List();
    for (var tax in providerTax) {
      var details;
      await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .doc(tax['tax'].path)
          .get()
          .then((value) => details = value.data());

      tempTax.add({
        'taxID': tax['identifier'],
        'taxName': details['taxID'],
        'taxRate': details['unitText'],
        'taxAmount': store.state.numberWorkedHours *
            offer.data()['price'] *
            details['value']
      });
```

Is this related to an incorrect call for futures to execute or is this related to the fact that .map executes lazily?

Comment: `Future.wait` returns a `Future` you are not awaiting on. The lazy behavior of `.map` is not a problem since `Future.wait` will consume all elements from the `Iterator` returned by `.map`. But I will say the last example is the more readable way to achieve want you are trying to do.

Comment: Neither example "returns" anything.  If you mean that `taxes` is *empty* (which is different from being `null`) in the first case and `tempTax` isn't in the second, then as @julemand101 said, you must do `await Future.wait(...)`.  Additionally, it's silly to use `await` and `.then()` together.  You can do `var details = (await FirebaseFirestore.instance.doc(tax['tax'].path).get()).data();`.